# Why doesn't this program segfault?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, segmentation-fault

What causes the output "Hello" when I enable -O for gcc ? Shouldn't it still segfault (according to this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Segmentation_fault_example)) ?

```
% cat segv.c 
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char * s = "Hello";
    s[0] = 'Y';
    puts(s);
    return 0;
}
% gcc segv.c && ./a.out 
zsh: segmentation fault  ./a.out
% gcc -O segv.c && ./a.out 
Hello
```

Comment: it says on platforms with memory protection. What platform are you on?

Comment: Accept one of the answers explaining that this is "Undefined Behavior", which gives the compiler license to emit anything whatsoever for the entire program.  But to answer your question, `"Hello"` is a `const char *`, which means its contents cannot be changed, so the optimizer is simply throwing away your attempt to modify it.  (This is a perfectly valid optimization, since the modification attempt itself invokes Undefined Behavior.)

Comment: No C string literals are not `const`; if they were, the assignment would be a constraint violation.  (They are `const` in C++.)  But yes, attempting to modify a string literal is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Keith:  Thanks for the correction.  I have been using C++ for the last few years so I forgot this detail.

Comment: @hroptatyr I'm on amd64 linux!

Comment: Whole lotta stuff in C is undefined behavior :-/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's **undefined behavior** (might crash, **might not do anything**, etc) to change string literals. Well explained in a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/strangeprob/strlitnomod.html).

> 6.4.5/6
>
> It is unspeciﬁed whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. If the program attempts to
> modify such an array,the behavior is undeﬁned.